# What is a prototype chain in regards to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm newer to Javascript, and I was wondering what exactly a "prototype chain" is in regards to Javascript Object Notation? What would I use it for?

EDIT:

**New Question:**

What are prototypes in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prototypes](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Using-the-Prototype-Property/) are a concept in JavaScript, but do not apply in [JSON](http://json.org/), which is purely a data transfer format.  JSON is a *subset* of JavaScript literal syntax, and one of the things it does not allow is functions.

EDIT: There are existing questions, such as [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work), explaining how it works in JavaScript

Comment: Oh so I *am* misunderstanding this.